# How to use Nokogiri::XML in order to take the attribute and value separately?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML with two data in the same line the ID and the product description ,such as, ID=18863 for paper A4, ID=18858 for TV...)

```
<products>
<product id="18863">paper A4 </product>
<product id="18858">TV Smart 12 </product>
<product id="18857">KitKat </product>
<product id="8816">Pen </product>
</products>
```

How do I take the ID and the description (paper A4, TV Smart 12...)?

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://url/file.xml"))
@doc = @doc.xpath(".//products/product")
```

Thank you

Comment: `@doc = @doc.xpath(".//products/product")` overwrites *@doc* with a node list. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

### Return a Hash of Content and Attributes

There's more than one way to do this, but the method I find most intuitive is to return a hash of each node's ID and contents. For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
@doc = Nokogiri::XML <<'EOF'
         <products>
           <product id="18863">paper A4 </product>
           <product id="18858">TV Smart 12 </product>
           <product id="18857">KitKat </product>
           <product id="8816">Pen </product>
         </products>
EOF
@doc.xpath('//products/product').
     map { |p| [p.attribute('id').value, p.content] }.to_h
```

This will return a hash, where each ID is the key and the product name is the value. For example, the code above returns:

```
{"18863"=>"paper A4 ",
 "18858"=>"TV Smart 12 ",
 "18857"=>"KitKat ",
 "8816"=>"Pen "}
```

You may want to use `p.content.strip` to remove the trailing whitespace from each product, too, but that's outside the scope of your original question.

*Note: The above works fine with Ruby 2.1.0 and the IRB console. Your mileage may vary with other Ruby versions, or with Pry.*

Answer (score 0):

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('/test.html'))
@doc.xpath('//products/product').each do |p|
       puts "#{p['id']} #{p.content}"
end
```

Result:

```
18863 paper A4 
18858 TV Smart 12 
18857 KitKat 
8816 Pen
```

More examples here - http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html